# Changes in the azan

Tags: adhan

In sunni sources, was the phrase "Hayya ala khayril amal" used in azan before? I understand that this phrase is used in the azan for shiaas, I wanted to understand if this phrase was used in the Prophet's (s. a. w) before muslims became divided into Shias and Sunnis.

Answer (score 1):

No this phrase was not in the Adhan at the time of our prophet (may peace be upon him) and it was added later on by Shiaa.